# Filling a select dropdown based on previous selection using Ajax.Updater

Tags: php, html, ajax, prototypejs

I'm trying to automatically fill a select dropdown with options based on the output from a php page.

I'm using the latest version of prototype and I've setup Ajax.Updater to get a php page with the correct parameters. I can easily display the result of this in a list, but how can I make this list become the options of a select box?

```
function get_second_list() {
new Ajax.Updater("second_list", "invBatchNumberFromProd.php?q="+$F("product"),{method:"get"});
}
```

And in my form I have

```
<label>Batch Number:</label><select id="second_list" name="batch">
    <option> 
    </option>
</select>
```

I can't figure out what to do from this point. My php page outputs a text list, but I can just as easily make this output whatever anyone recommends.

If I need to clarify anything at all then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out now.

I simply made the PHP page output each result within option tags and then created a div sandwiched between the select tags that is updated by the Ajax.Updater

```
<label>Batch Number:</label><select id="second_list" name="batch">
<div id="second_list">

</div>
</select>
```

And from the PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option>";
    echo $row['batchNumber'];
    echo "</option>";
}
```